# Url not being resolved in, 404 error django

Tags: django, django-views

I am not able to create an detail and update view using the `<pk>` and `<pk>/update/`, this is my url paths.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('form/',views.CompanyView.as_view(),name='company'),
    path('toy/',views.ToyView.as_view(),name='toy'),
    path('int:pk>/',views.CompanyDetailView.as_view()),
    path('int:pk>/update/',views.CompanyUpdateView.as_view())
]
```

my views looks like this,

```
class CompanyUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Company
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = '/company'

class CompanyDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Company
    fields = '__all__'

class CompanyView(generic.CreateView):
    model = Company
    template_name = 'company/company.html'
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = '/company'
```

`models.py` is

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email_id = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name

class Toys(models.Model):
    toy_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

This is the template used to in the `CreateView` and `UpdateView` since I am using a `ModelForm`

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            <h2> Company Form </h2>
        </legend>

        {{ form.as_p }}

    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Create view is working. When I got to a url `company/1/` or `company/1/update` I get a 404 error. What would be the reason for it and how to solve this

Comment: Try writing the urlpatterns as follows:-
path('/<int : pk>/',views.CompanyDetailView.as_view()),
    path('/<int : pk>/update/',views.CompanyUpdateView.as_view()) -> Add int too.

Comment: If writing "int" does not work then write "str" ->   path('/<str:pk>/',views.CompanyDetailView.as_view())

Comment: It's not working I have updated it with int,str and tried. I get a `Page not found` error

Comment: Did you try closing it with the "forward slashes(/)"?